# Report Viewer 2010 Localization

Tags: reportviewer

I have an ASP.NET project in which I am using Report Viewer 2010.
This project is multilingual everywhere, I made the localization by using Resource Files (.resx files).

How can I make the report multilingual in report viewer?

I can make the columns of the report multilingual by using report parameters, but how can I make the report's other staff like, next, print features multilingual?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6):

Implement `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportViewerMessages`, probably in the same project as your existing .resx files and use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` to help look up the localized resource for each of the properties. There are 39 new resources that will need to be defined.

In the Web.config for the project that hosts the `ReportViewer` control, add a new application setting with the key `ReportViewerMessages` and the value as the fully qualified class name. Add a reference to the assembly that contains your resources and then just ensure that the Web Form containing the `ReportViewer` control has the correct `UICulture` set, and you should be fully localized*.

Useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/SSRSReportLocalized.aspx

*ish. I still haven't worked out how to localize the client error messages produced by the `ReportViewer`.

Comment: The [`IReportViewerMessages2`][1] (ReportViewer 2008) and [`IReportViewerMessages3`][2] (ReportViewer 2010) interfaces define some client messages. 

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages2.aspx
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages3.aspx